# I am attempting to write a basic first program in allegro

Tags: c++, c, allegro

SO, I'm using the latest version and the latest version of Allegro, but on lines 6 and 12 I seem to have encountered some errors that are not yet clear to me. I am very new to C++ as well as Allegro, so any help would be very much appreciated.

For line 6 I have the error message: `"expected identifier or '(' before string constant`
For line 12, I have the error message: `"'display' undeclared (first use in this function)`

```
#include<allegro5/allegro.h>
#include<allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>

    int main()
    {
        ALLEGRO_DISPLAY "display";

        if(!al_init())
        {
            al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "Could not initialize Allegro 5", NULL, NULL);
        }
            display = al_create_display(800, 600);

            if(!display)
        {
            al_show_native_message_box(NULL, NULL, NULL, "Could not create Allegro Window", NULL, NULL);

        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Change "display" to display...remove the quotation marks.

Comment: http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/4.9.14/display.html#allegro_display ALLEGRO_DISPLAY is a struct.

Answer (score 3):

```
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY "display";
```

If you want to declare a variable of type `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY` with the name `display`, there should not be quotation marks.

But `al_create_display` returns not a `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY`, but a pointer to it, so the correct line would be:

```
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY* display;
```

Answer (score 1):

Change line 6 to:

```
ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display;
```

This line declares a variable named "`display`" of type (pointer to) `ALLEGRO_DISPLAY`. So line 12 should no longer cause an error.

Relevant documentation:

- [al_create_display](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/al_create_display)
- [ALLEGRO_DISPLAY](https://www.allegro.cc/manual/5/allegro_display)